# Find the asymptotic behavior of the coefficients of $\frac{e^{-z}(1+2z)^{3/2}}{\sqrt{1-2z}}$

Tags: combinatorics, asymptotics

> Use singularity analysis to find the asympotics of the coefficients of
>
> $$f(z) := \frac{e^{-z}(1+2z)^{3/2}}{\sqrt{1-2z}}$$

If I am not mistaken the singularities of $f$ are $\pm 1/2$. From the lecture I know the transfer theorem and the

> **Standard function scale:** Let $\alpha \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \mathbb{Z}_{\le 0}$. Then
> $$[z^n] (1-z)^{-\alpha} = \frac{n^{\alpha-1}}{\Gamma(\alpha)} \biggl(1+\mathcal{O}\biggl(\frac{1}{n}\biggr) \biggr).$$

I understand that by the definition of $\exp(\cdot)$ we have $e^{-z} = \sum_{n \ge 0} \frac{(-z)^n}{n!}$ and that by the binomial expansion of $(1-2z)^{-1/2}$ the standard function scale together with $\Gamma(1/2) = \sqrt{\pi}$ implies that

\begin{align}
[z^n]\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-2z}} &= [z^n]\sum_{k \ge 0} \binom{-1/2}{k}2^kz^k \\
&= \frac{2^n}{n^{1/2}\Gamma(1/2)} \biggl(1+\mathcal{O} \biggl(\frac{1}{n} \biggr)\biggr) \\
& = \sqrt{\frac{1}{n\pi}}\biggl(2^n+\mathcal{O} \biggl(\frac{2^n}{n} \biggr)\biggr).
\end{align}

However, I do not see what to do now, i.e what to do with the $(1+2z)^{3/2}$. Could you please give me a hint?

Comment: Why did you consider $\sqrt{1-2z}$ instead of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-2z}}$?

Comment: @Gary, you are right. I made an edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the general theory (which should be covered in your lectures; a good reference is *Analytic Combinatorics* by P. Flajolet and R. Sedgewick, section VI.5 "Multiple singularities"), the asymptotics is obtained by adding up the contributions of individual singularities. In our case, $z=1/2$ gives rise to $O(2^n n^{-1/2})$, while $z=-1/2$ gives the *negligible* $O(2^n n^{-5/2})$.

So, "around" $z=1/2$, we have $f(z)=2^{3/2}e^{-1/2}(1-2z)^{-1/2}\big(1+O(1-2z)\big)$, hence $$[z^n]f(z)=2^{n+3/2}(n\pi e)^{-1/2}\big(1+O(1/n)\big).$$